# How to add YouTrack bot hosted on myjetbrains.com to HipChat?

Tags: xmpp, bots, youtrack, hipchat

I've been trying to setup Jabber bot from YouTrack (the InCloud hosted one) to my HipChat. But failed.

I have tried to add the bot with [botusername]@myjetbrains.com (botusername is written in Jabber username field in Jabber notification section of YouTrack settings). But nothing happens.

I've also tried to send jabber message to my hipchat account but again nothing happens. I know I'm missing something here just don't know exactly what...

Comment: Please check https://help.hipchat.com/knowledgebase/articles/64438-how-to-connect-using-miranda, it should help in terms of which url and username should be used for the connection.